# How can I replace a "\\" for a "\"

Tags: r, gsub

I have something like this:

```
"jo\\xe3o madeira"
```

And I want this:

```
"jo\xe3o madeira"
```

How can I replace the \\ for a single \
I have tried stuff like this:

```
gsub("\\\\", "\\", "jo\\xe3o madeira")
```

And the output was:

```
"joxe3o madeira"
```

So it completely removed the "\"

Thanks in advance

Comment: It already is 1 backslash. Try `nchar("jo\\xe3o madeira")` and `nchar("joxe3o madeira")`

Comment: In case it's not clear from the answer/duplicate, when a string is printed by R it will "escape" special characters with a backslash. Special characters include backslashes. So the `\\` that you see printed is just a single `\` in the string, with an extra `\` printed to escape it. You can see whats "really" there by using `cat`, and indeed `cat("jo\\xe3o madeira")` will display the string with only the one backslash that is really there. The string only has one backslash, `cat` and `print` just offer different ways of looking at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using:-

```
str <- "jo\\xe3o madeira"
    cat(str)
```

This will give you:-

```
jo\xe3o madeira
```

Comment: That doesn't remove any backslashes. Just `cat` the original string - there's only one backslash to start with. (What your `gsub` does is remove all quotes `"`. Since there aren't any, it has no effect).

Comment: It's getting the output which was desired.

Comment: The `gsub` is pointless. `cat(str)` gives the output that was desired. The lesson is "use `cat` not `print` to see the string printed without escaping backslashes". Having the `gsub` to remove a quote and saying that it *"It'll just remove one backslash"* will just confuse people because it is incorrect.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Please delete the incorrect stuff at the top rather than just adding a corrected version underneath.

Comment: Removed previous thing.

Comment: Removed my downvote.